# write a list with attributes in a fasta file in r

Tags: r, attr, fasta

I have a ceratin list, with its head that looks like the following

```
> head(gg4)
[[1]]
  [1] "i" "a" "l" "t" "a" "l" "l" "g" "n" "m" "l" "v" "l" "w" "i" "v" "y" "k" "n" "h"
 [21] "t" "l" "r" "t" "i" "p" "n" "y" "f" "v" "i" "s" "l" "a" "c" "s" "d" "v" "v" "m"
 [41] "a" "a" "l" "a" "t" "p" "w" "s" "i" "a" "v" "l" "a" "v" "g" "k" "w" "p" "f" "d"


attr(,"name")
[1] "jgi|Nemve1|1499|gw.850.3.1"
```

I want to write it in a fasta format file..ie the output will be

```
> jgi|Nemve1|1499|gw.850.3.1

ialtallgnmlvlwivyknhtlrtipnyfvislacsdvvmaalatpwsiavlavgkwpfd
fvscqfqgfiviwaamaslqnlavmainrffrivkpahyrkffsasktrmyvllsyvyta
```

N.b when I use `write.fasta(sequences = gg4, names = names(gg4), file.out = "mf3a.fasta")`
I get

```
>

ialtallgnmlvlwivyknhtlrtipnyfvislacsdvvmaalatpwsiavlavgkwpfd
fvscqfqgfiviwaamaslqnlavmainrffrivkpahyrkffsasktrmyvllsyvyta
```

Comment: what is the first row of your output `jgi|Nemve1|1499|gw.850.3.1` supposed to be? I guess not the object name...

Comment: it is the attributes of the name..it is not the object name ..

Comment: this means it is supposed to be the first row in your output file?

Comment: yes i want to put the attributes name as the first row adjacent to  the ">" sign

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the `write.fasta` function, but try this.

```
write.fasta(sequences = gg4, names = attr(gg4,"name"), file.out = "mf3a.fasta")
```

If that fails take the verbose approach: The fasta format is a simple text file. Hence, the task boils down to adding an additional row at the beginning of the file after it has been created.

Save the file e.g. to `mf3a.fasta` as you did above:

```
write.fasta(sequences = gg4, names = names(gg4), file.out = "mf3a.fasta")
```

Then read in the file again and add the line you want at the top.
`attr(gg4,"name")` will get you the first line behind the `>`.

```
head <- paste0(">", attr(gg4,"name"))  # create header of ile
l <- readLines("mf3a.fasta")           # read fasta file without header
l <- c(head, l)                        # prepend header 
writeLines(l, "mf3a_2.fasta")          # write lines into new file
```

This will give you:

```
>jgi|Nemve1|1499|gw.850.3.1
ialtallgnmlvlwivyknhtlrtipnyfvislacsdvvmaalatpwsiavlavgkwpfd 
fvscqfqgfiviwaamaslqnlavmainrffrivkpahyrkffsasktrmyvllsyvyta
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The following function will extract the attribute (attr(,"name")) from gg4

```
attf<-function(x)
    {   l<-length(x)
        attv<-rep(NA,l)
            { for (i in 1:length(x))
                {   attv[i]<-attributes(x[[i]])$name}
            }
    return(attv)
    }
```

The the following should work

```
write.fasta(sequences = gg4, names = attf(gg4), file.out = "mf3a.fasta")
```